# Javascript "Not a function"

Tags: javascript, closures

The below given code gives an error `arguments.sort` is not a function. Is it because **arguments** object cannot be altered directly? Or is it something else.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function highest()
{ 
    return arguments.sort(function(a,b){ 
         return b - a; 
    }); 
} 
assert(highest(1, 1, 2, 3)[0] == 3, "Get the highest value."); 
assert(highest(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[1] == 4, "Verify the results.");
```

The `assert` function is as follows (Just in case)

```
function assert(pass, msg){
   var type = pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
   jQuery("#results").append("<li class='" + type + "'><b>" + type + "</b> " + msg + "</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return [].sort.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
   return b - a;
})
```

**Edit:** As @Esailija pointed out, this doesn't return a real array, it just returns the `arguments` object which is an array-like object. It's fine for iterating and accessing properties by index, but that's about it.

Comment: But this doesn't return an array :x

Comment: @Esailija: Right, didn't notice that, it returns an `arguments` object. It should be fine for this case, but yeah OP might want an actual array.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `arguments` is not an array and doesn't have the `sort` method.

You can use this trick to convert it to an array:

```
function highest()
{ 
    return [].slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a,b){ 
         return b - a; 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You highest function isn't passing any argument inside

```
function highest(arguments)
{ 
    return arguments.sort(function(a,b){ 
         return b - a; 
    }); 
}
```

and should work with an array

```
highest([1, 1, 2, 3])[0]
```